# Can't make divs stack vertically inside td table cell

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to build a legend for a pie chart. Only the legend's code is shown below. I want the little colored box to float to the left, and the text (label) immediately to the right of the box. So think of each box-label pair as a unit that should go together. The next box-label pair should stack vertically underneath. I cannot make this vertical stack happen. Everything tries to keep flowing to the right, instead of wrapping and stacking underneath. Please help.

```
<td align="right" valign="top">
<div id='divDashboardNotStarted' class='PieLegendText' onclick='openDashboardInfo(this)' style='top: 15px;display: inline-block;clear:left'>
<div style='float:left; width:11px;height:11px;background-color:#DD6C40'>    </div>
<div style='float:left'>&nbsp;<b>69% (88) Not Started</b></div>
</div>
<div id='divDashboardInProgress' class='PieLegendText' onclick='openDashboardInfo(this)' style='top: 25px;display: inline-block;clear:left'>
<div style='float:left; width:11px;height:11px;background-color:#ACD5E5'>  </div>
<div style='float:left'>&nbsp;<b>5% (7) In Progress</b></div>
</div>
<div id='divDashboardCompleted' class='PieLegendText' onclick='openDashboardInfo(this)' style='top: 35px;display: inline-block;clear:left'>
<div style='float:left; width:11px;height:11px;background-color:#7FAABB'>    </div>
<div style='float:left'>&nbsp;<b>9% (12) Completed</b></div>
</div>
<div id='divDashboardIncomplete' class='PieLegendText' onclick='openDashboardInfo(this)' style='top: 45px;'>
<div style='float:left; width:11px;height:11px;background-color:#5f7d89'>  </div>
<div style='float:left'>&nbsp;<b>12% (16) Incomplete</b></div>
</div>
<div id='divDashboardCancelled' class='PieLegendText' onclick='openDashboardInfo(this)' style='top: 55px;'>
<div style='float:left; width:11px;height:11px;background-color:#efcd3f'>    </div>
<div style='float:left'>&nbsp;<b>4% (5) Cancelled</b></div>
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: It's more common practice to `clear: both;` with a block-object below the last used *set* of floats. From that point on the float influential behavior will be nullified again and won't intervene with the rest of the markup. If you want them to stack only; why not remove float from it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with your .PieLegendText divs. You need to give each one a width of 100% and add a style for clear:left for each one.

```
.PieLegendText {
    clear:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UyJtx/

Alternatively, you could remove the 'display:inline-block' style from the first three .PieLegendText divs and just use a 'clear:left' style in your css for .PieLegendText.

```
.PieLegendText {
    clear:left;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/twEwX/

Comment: clear:left was the silver bullet. THANK YOU!! (though I don't understand why it worked in my css class, but not in my inline style!)

Comment: No problem! And the reason it didn't work was that you didn't have it in the last two divs, it was only an inline clear:left in the first three.

Answer (score 0):

```
.PieLegendText{
overflow:auto;
}
```

You have to basically clear the floats for everything to fall under each other. As suggested by aarryy, you could add the width 100% but it is not a scalable solution.